# Why if(key in null); throw exception while for(key in null); does not, it is the language design flaws on it?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

From a language design perspective, why:

`if('k' in null);`

`TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'k' in null`

BUT:

`for('k' in null);`

prints `undefined`

in ECMAScript spec:

- [11.8.7 The in operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.8.7)
- [12.6.4 The for-in Statement](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.4)

Is it the language design flaw?

Comment: Well... it wouldn't be the first Javascript oddity, would it?

Comment: A for loop iterates any keys in whatever you pass it, and the `k` is a variable. You're instead passing the string `'k'` to the for loop, and that doesn't work, and naturally the for loop never iterates if there are no keys, without throwing errors as that would cause a ton of issues, while just using `in` to look for keys in anything that isn't an object fails, with errors, as it should.

Comment: @adeneo `typeof null` = "object", so technically it is looking for keys in an object.

Comment: @RUJordan nope. The `typeof` return is a language design oversight, not its behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a design perspective, it's hard to say what the appropriate return value of `k in null` should be (`true` is clearly wrong, but `false` is misleading), but it's easy to say that in the `for-in` statement, you should just skip the loop.

I don't *agree* with this decision at all - I think that `for (k in null)` should throw an error, especially if running in strict mode. But you can see how the difference would arise.